# TSharedPtr global variable

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I am writing some cpp code for an unreal engine plugin (UE4).
I am having an issue with the following line, with the TSharedPtr. Currently I can only access it inside the method where it is initiallized, but I would like to access is within the whole class.

```
TSharedPtr<ROSMessages::sensor_msgs::Image> ImageMessage(new ROSMessages::sensor_msgs::Image());
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Is this line from the class definition or from the method, which initializes it?

Comment: This is the line I use inside the method to initialize it. But i need to access it in other methods too. I tried to declare it like this in the header file: TSharedPtr<ROSMessages::sensor_msgs::Image> ImageMessage;   But i can't figure out the syntact to initialize it properly.